# How to select [n] Items from a CSV list to assign them to a variable and afterwards remove those items and save the file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I'm parsing a CSV file to get the names of folders which I need to copy to another location. Because there are hundreds of them, I need to select the first 10 or so and run the copy routine but to avoid copying them again I'm removing them from the list and saving the file.

I'll run this on a daily scheduled task to avoid having to wait for the folders to finish copying. I'm having a problem using the 'Select' and 'Skip' options in the code (see below), if I remove those lines the folders are copied (I'm using empty folders to test) but if I have them in, then nothing happens when I run this in PowerShell.

I looked around in other questions about similar issues but did not find anything that answers this particular issue selecting and skipping rows in the CSV.

```
$source_location = 'C:\Folders to Copy'
$folders_Needed = gci $source_location
Set-Location -Path $source_location
$Dest = 'C:\Transferred Folders'
$csv_name = 'C:\List of Folders.csv'
$csv_Import = Get-Content $csv_name


foreach($csv_n in $csv_Import | Select-Object -First 3){
    foreach ($folder_Tocopy in $folders_Needed){        
        if("$folder_Tocopy" -contains "$csv_n"){        
        Copy-Item -Path $folder_Tocopy -Destination $Dest -Recurse -Verbose        
        }
    }
    $csv_Import | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Out-File -FilePath $csv_name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with skip/first as in your example, but I cannot really test it without your sample data. Also, it seems wrong that you write the same output to the csv file at every iteration of the loop. And I assume it's not a csv file but actually just a plain text file, a list of folders? Just folder names or full paths? (I assume the first.)

Anyways, here is my suggested update to the script (see comments):

```bsh
$source_location = 'C:\Folders to Copy'
$folders_Needed = Get-ChildItem $source_location
$Dest = 'C:\Transferred Folders'
$csv_name = 'C:\List of Folders.csv'
$csv_Import = @(Get-Content $csv_name)
# optional limit
# set this to $csv_Import.Count if you want to copy all folders
$limit = 10

# loop over the csv entries
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $csv_Import.Count -and $i -lt $limit; $i++) {
    # current line in the csv file
    $csv_n = $csv_Import[$i]
    # copy the folder(s) which name matches the csv entry
    $folders_Needed | where {$_.Name -eq $csv_n} | Copy-Item -Destination $Dest -Recurse -Verbose
    # update the csv file (skip all processed entries)
    $csv_Import | Select-Object -Skip ($i + 1) | Out-File -FilePath $csv_name
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marsze, this works like a charm and your comments made it very clear to follow. Regarding the data I used, since I wanted to test this before touching the real folders which are pretty big, I created 10 empty folders and a CSV in Excel with those names. This is not that important but how would I go about writing a log of the folders that completed copying to know when they are done? the thinking is that if I have 100GB being copied I'd like to know that it was successful and that it didn't stop midway.

Comment: Thanks again Marsze, only the last folder copied is being added to the log, I guess I have to work it in the loop. Also, will the log be adding folders even if they fail to copy, maybe due to an error?

Comment: You're right, I missed the `-Append` but now it's working the right way. I just have to test with a big folder and see if it gets logged when the process errors out. Thanks for your time, I truly appreciate your prompt responses.

Comment: @Robinsper You're welcome. If you run into any other issues feel free to leave a comment. I will check in again later.

Comment: I'm sorry to be such a pain, don't mean to use so much of your time with my simple-minded questions. If I want to check that the files exist (in case they are complete and I need to switch to another path for instance) do I run the check on the folder name from the row like this: `code` if ($csv_name) {
        do stuff
    } else {
        do other stuff
    }

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer. I tried adding the `Test-Path $Dest` to the end of the code, but not sure I'm using it right. Here's what I added:  `code` If (Test-Path $Dest) {
    $csv_n + ' - Copied from: ' + $source_location | Out-File $log_File -Append
} else {
        'No Files Matching in the Location ' | Out-File $log_File -Append
    }

Comment: you're a lifesaver, it works great! Thanks a million!